# Mysql multiple joins from 3 tables. clueless

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. i'm looking to connect each table but unsure how. 
I'm looking to get all the information from table 1 and from the other tables only if it matches the fields in table 1

```
table 1 (id, name_1, name_2, name_3, info_1, info_2
```

`table 2 (description,info_1,otherstuff_1)`

`table 3 (name_1,name_2,name_3,random_1)`

I have tried doing a join but feel that I was using the wrong syntax.

if done correctly. I'm hoping to get

`id,name_1.table3,info_1.table2,name_2.table3`

any help is appreciated

Comment: Add some sample data and the expected result please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table names appear before column names.
Try something like:
`select t1.id, t3.name_1, t2.info_1, t3.name_2
from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
where t1.info_1 = t2.info_1
and t1.name_1 = t3.name_1`

Answer (score 0):

You can join tables by this query

`select t1.id,t3.name1,t2.info_1,t3.name_2 from table1 as t1 join table2 as t2 on t1.info_1 = t2.info_1 join table3 as t3 on t1.name_1 = t3.name_1 and 
t1.name_2 = t3.name_2 and t1.name_3.t3.name_3`